# Just installed django-tinymce but the HTMLField is not showing up in the admin view

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce, django-tinymce

I used pip to install it, and followed the usage directions found here: http://django-tinymce.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.5/docs/.build/html/usage.html under the section "The HTMLField model field type". I re-synced the db (not even sure that was needed), restarted apache2, and yet the text field is still just a textarea.

Any suggestions on what I am missing? Do I need to somehow link the django-tinymce templates into my media directory?

EDIT: Initialization code for the texarea, as requested:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">tinyMCE.init({"relative_urls": false, "spellchecker_languages": "Arabic=ar,Bulgarian=bg,Bengali=bn,Bosnian=bs,Catalan=ca,Czech=cs,Welsh=cy,Danish=da,German=de,Greek=el,+English / British English=en,Spanish / Argentinean 
Spanish=es,Estonian=et,Basque=eu,Persian=fa,Finnish=fi,French=fr,Frisian=fy,Irish=ga,Galician=gl,Hebrew=he,Hindi=hi,Croatian=hr,Hungarian=hu,Indonesian=id,Icelandic=is,Italian=it,Japanese=ja,Georgian=ka,Khmer=km,Kannada=kn,Korean=ko,Lithuanian=lt,Latvian=lv,Macedonian=mk,Mongolian=mn,Dutch=nl,Norwegian=no,Norwegian Bokmal=nb,Norwegian Nynorsk=nn,Polish=pl,Portuguese / Brazilian Portuguese=pt,Romanian=ro,Russian=ru,Slovak=sk,Slovenian=sl,Albanian=sq,Serbian / Serbian Latin=sr,Swedish=sv,Tamil=ta,Telugu=te,Thai=th,Turkish=tr,Ukrainian=uk,Vietnamese=vi,Simplified Chinese / Traditional Chinese=zh", "elements": "id_Body", "language": "en", "directionality": "ltr", "theme": "simple", "strict_loading_mode": 1, "mode": "exact"})</script>
```

Comment: have a look at the source code of the page  - there you should find your initialization settings for the tinymce - please post them here

Answer (score 1):

**Your config:**

```
tinyMCE.init({"relative_urls": false,
          "spellchecker_languages": "Arabic=ar,Bulgarian=bg,Bengali=bn,Bosnian=bs,Catalan=ca,Czech=cs,Welsh=cy,Danish=da,German=de,Greek=el,+English / British English=en,Spanish / Argentinean Spanish=es,Estonian=et,Basque=eu,Persian=fa,Finnish=fi,French=fr,Frisian=fy,Irish=ga,Galician=gl,Hebrew=he,Hindi=hi,Croatian=hr,Hungarian=hu,Indonesian=id,Icelandic=is,Italian=it,Japanese=ja,Georgian=ka,Khmer=km,Kannada=kn,Korean=ko,Lithuanian=lt,Latvian=lv,Macedonian=mk,Mongolian=mn,Dutch=nl,Norwegian=no,Norwegian Bokmal=nb,Norwegian Nynorsk=nn,Polish=pl,Portuguese / Brazilian Portuguese=pt,Romanian=ro,Russian=ru,Slovak=sk,Slovenian=sl,Albanian=sq,Serbian / Serbian Latin=sr,Swedish=sv,Tamil=ta,Telugu=te,Thai=th,Turkish=tr,Ukrainian=uk,Vietnamese=vi,Simplified Chinese / Traditional Chinese=zh",
          "elements": "id_Body",
          "language": "en",
          "directionality": "ltr",
          "theme": "simple",
          "strict_loading_mode": 1,
          "mode": "exact"
})
```

works fine for me when i change the parameter **"[elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/mode)"** to the name of one of my textareas on my page. I suppose you do not have a html element with the name "id_Body", right? If so, change the parameter to the name of one of your html-elements on your page.

Comment: I actually do have a textarea with id="id_Body", and it's where I got this init code from. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, difficult to say.
What happens if you change the mode to "textareas"?